# Cannot install latest version of moodle4mac on Catalina

Tags: moodle, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install moodle4mac on Catalina via a .dmg file. The .dmg file mounts okay. However, when I try to drag the MAMP folder to the Applications folder, I get the message "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items."

When install dialog is showing 4 folders;

.DocumentRevisions-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.fseventsd

The first three have no go signs on the folders suggesting that these are the problematic ones. I have checked the read/write permissions of the Applications folder, which looks fine. I have also run `sudo spctl --master-disable` which gives me the opportunity to download apps from anywhere, but this does not make any difference.

Any pointers greatly welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. It turns out the culprit was Sophos Home Antivirus. There was no indication in any of the error messages that Sophos was blocking this, hence I did not put two and two together. However, a warning message about the mounted volume popped up this morning, and I was able to trace this back to Sophos. It would be great if Sophos / MacOS could provide more detailed messages regarding such errors in future.